# structureMap in a multiTier application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have a asp.net mvc app having three layers
1. dataAccess layer (class library)
2. business layer (class library)
3. web layer (asp.net mvc project)

and also have a domain project (class library for poco)

I am doing the structureMap mappings in my Application_start of the MVC project, but to map the TYPES in dataAccesslayer (for eg. personRepository with IPersonReository) i need the reference of the DAL in my web layer, which i dont think is correct.

What are your suggestions 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a pragmatic approach what you are doing may be okay **if you can keep the discipline** and never use the DAL from the Web Layer. However, once the reference is there, this can be surprisingly hard to do - and what about other developers on the project?

A better option is to **split the web layer into two layers**:

1. The **Application Bootstrapping layer**. This is the real web project, but apart from bootstrapping the container and implementing the Views (.aspx pages) there should be nothing else. This is what we call a [Humble Executable](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html). It will contain references to all other projects in order to compose them (via the DI container), but otherwise it doesn't do anything. We call this the [Register Resolve Release pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx).
2. An **Application Model layer**. This project would contain all of your application logic (as opposed to domain logic): View Models and Controllers. It needs no reference to the DAL, but will get implementations injected into it by the DI container.

Comment: Thanks so much Mark...The Application Bootstrapping layer will be a asp.net mvc project and the Application Model layer will be a class library project ?

Comment: Yes, the Application Model layer can be a class library project, but since Controllers are going to be there, it will still reference the appropriate ASP.NET MVC assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in having a reference to the DAL in your web project as long as you are not directly making calls to that assembly. But if you are uncomfortable with that approach, you can use a Registry in your Business layer and there register types for the DAL. Since the Web layer would anyway need to have a reference to the Business layer, you can use that registry from the Business layer in Web's App start

Here is some sample code

The registry class in your Bsns layer

```
public class BusinessRegistry:Registry
{
    public BusinessRegistry()
    {
         For<IDALInterface1>().Use<DALImpl1>();
    }
}
```

and in the Application start method

```
var container = new Container(x => x.AddRegistry(new BusinessRegistry()));
```

Comment: what if suppose there are 5 layers....though we can make registry in each layers but we'll have to initialize them in the application_start only...so we'll anyhow need the reference of all the 5 layers...is there any work around for this...

Comment: 5 layers means 5 projects. If that were the case, I'd go back to redesign the whole thing. The lesser the projects, the better. Anyway to your original question, I'd recommend what @Seemann suggested below, have a bootstrapping project that would init the DI container with all dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, a reference to your DAL project is not the end of the world unless you use it incorrectly (or maybe at all in your web project).  I prefer to have an Infrastructure project contains all things related to cross-cutting concerns.  Among other things, this includes my Logging and IoC Container.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your answer but i think it is safe to not have the reference in the first place itself..

Comment: I agree which is why my answer tells you how to remove references from your Web to your Dal